# PHP CRUD helper without MVC

Tags: php

I'm used to build a high amount of small PHP apps to do many little things, usually involving no more than a couple of database tables.

Since those small PHP apps are for myself, I don't even need an authentication layer (at most, an identification layer, if I use the PHP app with my wife and I want to understand the user).

I'm getting tired of building everything from scratch, I've even built my own custom library to reuse the most common code, but it's not enough.

Using CMS (like WordPress or Drupal) or MVC frameworks (like CakePHP) is way too much overkill.

I just need some kind of software that starting from a database table builds up few PHP web pages that do CRUD of that table.

I searched all over internet but I have been unable to find anything that matches my needs. Am I just unlucky? Is there no PHP software that does CRUD no-MVC?

Comment: I know you said MVC is to much overkill, but have you looked at yii?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look to [Doctrine's tools](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects.html) which provide various and independants helper/libraries for database manipulations.

For instance it offers an **ORM** for hight level programming.

There is also a **Migration** tool which can be useful to deploy schema updates.